# MYSQL select DISTINCT chat conversations

Tags: mysql, chat, distinct

Im trying to get distinct conversations between 2 users, by the latest message. and I am lost.

my table is set up like

```
iD |  From  |  to  |  Message | Read |   Created_at
1  |   2    |   1  |  blah1   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:15:24
2  |   1    |   2  |  blah2   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:16:24
3  |   2    |   1  |  blah3   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:17:24
4  |   2    |   3  |  blah4   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:18:24
5  |   1    |   5  |  blah5   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:19:24
6  |   1    |   3  |  blah6   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:20:24
```

i want a result of each conversation, without duplicates.

so, for example. if selecting all conversations with user ID 1. i need a result like this...

```
iD |  From  |  to  |  Message | Read |   Created_at
3  |   2    |   1  |  blah3   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:17:24
5  |   1    |   5  |  blah5   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:19:24
6  |   1    |   3  |  blah6   |   0  |   2019-01-11 02:20:24
```

everything i have tried has resulted in duplicates of conversations of 1 to 2 as well as 2 to 1

and everything ive searched for on here does not work for me.

Comment: Why aren't rows with `iD` = 1 or 2 included for user ID 1 as they have `From`/`to` fields that match 1 too (`SELECT ... WHERE From=1 OR To=1`)? What's a duplicate conversation actually look like?

Comment: sorry, should clarify, id 1 and 2 are a part of the id 3 conversation.  i want to get a list of conversations, with the latest message.

Comment: #3 was the latest message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the time of the latest conversation between a given user (in my example I am using user 1) and any other users using this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `From` = 1 THEN `To` ELSE `From` END AS other, MAX(Created_at) AS latest
FROM conversations
WHERE `From` = 1 OR `To` = 1
GROUP BY other
```

Then it's just a question of `JOIN`ing that to the whole table to get the details of the latest message between two users:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM conversations c
JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN `From` = 1 THEN `To` ELSE `From` END AS other, MAX(Created_at) AS latest
      FROM conversations
      WHERE `From` = 1 OR `To` = 1
      GROUP BY other) m
  ON (c.From = 1 AND c.To = m.other OR c.To = 1 AND c.From = m.other) AND c.Created_at = m.latest
```

Output:

```
iD  From    to  Message     Read    Created_at
3   2       1   blah3       0       2019-01-11 02:17:24
5   1       5   blah5       0       2019-01-11 02:19:24
6   1       3   blah6       0       2019-01-11 02:20:24
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=468f1f08bcbd51cfc9894c65a891e786)

Comment: this is exactly what i needed! i was close but so far away haha. thanks!!!